# Counting words with minimum length in java

Tags: java

Write your code in the file WordCount.java. Your code should go into a method with the following signature. You may write your own main method to test your code. The graders will ignore your main method:

```
public static int countWords(String original, int minLength){}
```

Your method should count the number of words in the sentence that meet or exceed minLength (in letters). For example, if the minimum length given is 4, your program should only count words that are at least 4 letters long.

Words will be separated by one or more spaces. Non-letter characters (spaces, punctuation, digits, etc.) may be present, but should not count towards the length of words.

Hint: write a method that counts the number of letters (and ignores punctuation) in a string that holds a single word without spaces. In your countWords method, break the input string up into words and send each one to your method.

I am trying to get the minimum length of the word in the code, without it counting punctuation marks and such. how do i do that? Also, I will get rid of the main method as it will be added automatically. How do i make the program automatically add a space after the last word?

```
public class WordCounts
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");              
    String sentence = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("minLength");
    int minLength=in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence,minLength)+ " words.");
}

public static int countWords(String str, int minLength)
{
int count = 0;
int c=0;

for (int i=0;i<=str.length()-1;i++)
{
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ')
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)>='a' && str.charAt(i)<='z') //to check only      for alphabets.
        c++;

    }
    if(c>=minLength)
    {
         count++;
         c=0;
    }
    }
return count;

}
}
```

Comment: `minLength` is defined only in the `main` method, you can't access it from inside `countWords`. Declare it as a field instead.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, what do you want to do with int minLength=IO.readInt();

Comment: what does this mean: **int minLength=IO.readInt();**   ???

Comment: i'm trying to get the minimum number of letters a word should have to be counted as a word. for example the user/main method can define the minimum length of a word as 4 letters for it to be counted in the word count. I tried using the IO module to accept user input in the main method.

Comment: We don't know what the "IO module" is. Is that something your teacher provided you? Or are you talking about `System.in`?

Comment: Your code is not resembling your problem statement. Please be more clear

Comment: alright, forget the IO module. Let me put it this way. This code without the minLength statement counts every character after a space as a word. But, i want it to only count words which have more than a certain number of letters. How do I do that?

Comment: See the second paragraph of your problem statement for the correct signature for the method `countWords`.

Comment: @RajeevSingh I think Java's String `length()` method is constant time since String stores its length as a final int internally and simply returns that. [Source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)

Comment: @Mage Xy thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem statement correctly. Correct me if I am wrong.

You want to check that the length of entered string should be greater than the minimum entered length. For that you need to pass the `minLength` variable to the method `countWords`. And then you are checking that the character is valid or not using  `if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')`

Updated method

```
public static int countWords(String str, int minLength)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<=str.length()-1;i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ' &&   str.length()>=minLength)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
 }
```

In your main method, take input using `Scanner`

```
int minLength=in.nextInt();
```

Comment: WordCount.java:17: error: method countWords in class WordCount cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");
                                                ^
  required: String,int
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
WordCount.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ' && str.length>=minLength)
                                                                   ^  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable str of type String

Comment: You need to call the method as `countWords(sentence,minLength);`

Comment: java:25: error: cannot find symbol
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ' && str.length>=minLength)
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable str of type String

Comment: i believe i have to refer to it with something other than length?

Comment: its `minLength` dude not `minlength`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass minLength as a parameter to the countWords function.  That way, you will be able to access this variable in the countWords function.  You will also want to loop through the string character by character and keep track of how many letters you have seen, call it "numLetters".  Check if the character is present in the string "aAbBcC....yYzZ" to ensure it is a letter, and if it is present, then add 1 to "numLetters". If you reach the end of the input or reach a space, then check if numLetters is greater than minLength, and if so, add 1 to count.  Reset numLetters to 0 and keep going until you reach the end of the string.

e.g. to get the character:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    char c = str.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: well that's what i am trying to do. but i don't know how to do that. i know i should use a for loop but how do i count every individual letter? should it be like for(int i=0; i<str.charAt(' ');i++)?

Comment: for  (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this:

Also you have to pass the value of minLength to function You cannot access minLength outside main.

```
public static int countWords(String str,int minLength)
{
    int count = 0;int c=0;
    for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' ')
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)>='a' && str.charAt(i)<='z')
            c++;
            continue;
        }
        if(c>=minLength)
        {
             count++;
        }
        c=0;
    }
    if(c>=minLength)
    return count+1;
    else
    return count;
 }
}
```

Comment: hey, this works really well. Now, how do i account for only letters in minLength and not punctuations? For example: f,,..;o'';..r should be considered 3 letters. How would i do that?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
            if(isLetter(str.charAt(i))) //to check only for alphabets.
               ^
  symbol:   method isLetter(char)
  location: class WordCount. Where do i define isLetter? and how do i define it?

Comment: You can modify the condition to check for Uppercase letters also

Comment: But where do I define isLetter? And how do I define it?

Comment: @Shabab Huq you don't have to define it...i changed the condition

Comment: try running it. It's not working even after it compiles. like if i type in "hey how are you doing today" and set minimum length to 4 it says it has 3 words. for other examples too it seems like its counting one more word than it should. also i initialized c at the beginning to 0. it says c hasn't been initialized, otherwise

Comment: also its not counting the last word because the last word doesn't end in a space

Comment: I edited the code to count the last word also...now it works well....if u find any bug , let me know